# meaning of "~たらことだ"

Tags: meaning

I found this sentence in Japanese literature:

> ぐすぐすしていて、災難にあったらことだ。

Does anyone know what is the meaning of "~たらことだ"?

Answer (score 3):

This こと (事 in kanji) is a regular noun meaning "a serious matter", "a bad trouble". ～たらことだ means "it's very bad if ～" or "will run into trouble if ～". Practically, you can learn the following set phrases:

- (～ては/たら) + こと + だ/になる <sub>(this こと is interchangeable with 大問題, 大事, etc)</sub>
- ことを起こす to cause trouble
- ことが起きる something bad happens

  > ことが起きてからでは遅い。
  > If an accident happens, it's too late.

---

> #### [こと](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8/#jn-80340)
>
> ２ 大変な事態。重大な出来事。「失敗したら事だ」「ここで事を起こしたら苦労が水の泡だ」

> #### [事](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BA%8B)
>
> 2. incident; occurrence; event; something serious; trouble; crisis​